# Docker compose build with remote docker host and buildkit

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-buildkit, buildx

So I have dug into gitlab-ci and I have an app that needs to connect to a Strapi instance during build time. I have found out that due to several things this is really hard.

I will put links to different topics regarding this:

Specify network to use during buildtime:

1. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7911
2. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network

Networking during build time has been borked:

1. https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/978

---

Now my CI file.

```yaml
     - docker context create remote_dev_server --docker "host=ssh://$DEV_SERVER_USER@$DEV_SERVER_IP"
      - docker context use remote_dev_server
        #    - set BUILDKIT_HOST=docker-container://buildx_buildkit_www-builder0
      - docker buildx create --name www-builder --driver docker-container --driver-opt 'network=custom-network' --platform linux/amd64,linux/386 --use
      - docker buildx ls
      - docker buildx inspect
      # Set current builder instance 
      #- docker buildx use www-builder
      #  If current builder is inactive, use prior advice and force build container creation
      #- echo "FROM scratch" | docker buildx build -
      #- DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker compose build
      - docker compose build
      - docker compose push
```

As you can see I have many commented lines of things I have tested.

NB! This works with DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0

My docker compose file:

```yaml
  ---
  version: '3.8'
  services:
    app-static:
      image: ${IMAGE_APP_TAG_STATIC}
      build:
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.static
        network: ${NETWORK_NAME}
        args:
          PORT: ${PORT}
          STRAPI_URL: ${STRAPI_URL}
          STATIC_PAGE: true
      env_file: .env
      deploy:
        restart_policy:
          condition: on-failure
      networks:
        - ansible-controlled-network
    app-ssr:
      image: ${IMAGE_APP_TAG_SSR}
      build:
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.ssr
        network: ${NETWORK_NAME}
        args:
          PORT: ${PORT}
          STRAPI_URL: ${STRAPI_URL}
          STATIC_PAGE: false
      env_file: .env
      deploy:
        restart_policy:
          condition: on-failure
      networks:
        - ansible-controlled-network
  networks:
    ansible-controlled-network:
      name: ${NETWORK_NAME}
      external: true
```

As you can see I have an externally created docker network that hosts the Strapi instance I need to acccess during build time. It works without buildkit, but buildkit borks it.

```
$ docker compose build
#1 [internal] booting buildkit
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1
#1 [internal] booting buildkit
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 8.8s done
#1 creating container buildx_buildkit_www-builder0 0.0s done
#1 ERROR: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/buildx_buildkit_www-builder0" is already in use by container "8791d0757fce91ae84f600df2927fae2b0033458721cbaae0823123548cfa067". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
------
 > [internal] booting buildkit:
------
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 8.7s done
#1 creating container buildx_buildkit_www-builder0 0.0s done
#1 CANCELED
Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/buildx_buildkit_www-builder0" is already in use by container "8791d0757fce91ae84f600df2927fae2b0033458721cbaae0823123548cfa067". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

As you can see buildkit gets into a weird state.

Comment: Can you please share the docker client version?

Comment: Currently im running docker 24.0.2 from the APT repository. Its constantly updated as the repo gets active updates quickly.

Comment: I seem to have run into another issue with running DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 now. 
`unable to prepare context: path "" not found`

Comment: It seems to have been related to the `build` part of my docker-compose.

It worked before with `dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.static`, but it seems now you need to use ```
context: .
dockerfile: Dockerfile.static
```

These need to be separate